# Spring Boot + JUnit 5: cannot globally set test instance lifecycle

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5

In my Spring Boot (v2) project I'm using JUnit 5 to implement unit tests and I'd like to set test instance lifecycle to `PER_CLASS`.

It correctly works if I set via annotation in each test class, like this:

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```

but I'd like to set globally using the JUnit property:

```
junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default=per_class
```

I tried to put the property in `application.properties`, then in `junit-platform.properties` but neither seems to work.

What's the correct way to set this globally?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it with `JUnitPlatformOptions` in `build.gradle`

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        systemProperty("junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default", "per_class")
    }
}
```